# FlutterPi - Error when running cabin-demo in

Tags: flutter

I follow this guideline from this [link](https://github.com/ardera/flutter-pi#-building-flutter-pi-on-the-raspberry-pi) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5C90jVS7xg&t=6s).

1. I have installed raspberrypi *flutter binary* manually based on this [link](https://github.com/ardera/flutter-engine-binaries-for-arm).
2. Download and built *cabin demo apps* from this [link](https://github.com/KDAB/cabin-demo).
3. Build in linux machine and copy to rasberry-pi machine.
4. But i get this following error:

```
flutter: The Dart VM service is listening on http://127.0.0.1:46225/_o4DEwTeGs4=/
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(91)] Dart Error: Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version.
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(144)] Could not prepare isolate.
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(422)] Could not create root isolate.
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(614)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
[compositor] Preferred framebuffer depth for hardware cursor is not supported by flutter-pi.
[compositor] Could not mmap dumb buffer for uploading the hardware cursor icon. mmap: Invalid argument
```

Any suggestion what i have missed from all steps? And thanks in advance.

This is my raspberry env

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this based on his helps in this [comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5C90jVS7xg&t=124s).

Basically it happens it doesn't have same *binary* which is listed in *flutter/bin/internal/engine.version* .

To make it uses the same binary version do following steps:

- In app dev computer execute: `flutter channel stable` and `flutter upgrade`. It will update and show you which binary version used. For example it looks like `cdbeda788a293fa29665dc3fa3d6e63bd221cb0d` .
- Make sure this binary has same version with `https://github.com/ardera/flutter-engine-binaries-for-arm` , look at directory `arm64/engine.version`. Just pull and install once again based on *how to*.
- Pull the lastest code from *flutter-pi* repo and install it once again.
- Build *cabin-demo* in app development machine and transfer its assets to rasberry (follow how to in flutter-pi project).
- Run application in rasberry using flutter-pi.
- If it shows `[compositor] Could not present frame. drmModeAtomicCommit: Permission denied [modesetting] Could not commit atomic request. drmModeAtomicCommit: Permission denied`.

  - Make sure **currently no flutter-pi app is running** or `killall flutterpi`
  - Press `ctrl` `alt` `F2` to switch to terminal mode. And run app with `flutter-pi` once again.

NOTE:

1. I build, copy and run cabin demo with *old-method*. I dont use `fluterpi_tool`. It is why i need to install `flutter-engine-binary`.